# How to make scripts just run one time when app start?

Tags: typescript, next.js

I try to use facebook API for chat plugin.but it just work when i put the script in component like this

FacebookPlugin.tsx

```
import Script from "next/script";
import React from "react";

const FacebookMessenger = () => {

  return (
    <div>
      <div id="fb-root"></div>

      <div id="fb-customer-chat" className="fb-customerchat"></div>

      <Script strategy="lazyOnload">
        {`
          facebook scripts is there
        `}
      </Script>
   
    </div>
  );
};

export default FacebookMessenger;
```

and put it in _app.tsx, but when i push to another route,this component run again, and the plugin seem just work one time so it not display anymore,so i try to put all code in _document.tsx

```
export default class Document extends NextDocument {
  render() {
    return (
      <Html>
        <Head>
          <link
            href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons"
            rel="stylesheet"
          />
        </Head>
        <body>
          {/* Make Color mode to persists when you refresh the page. */}

          <ColorModeScript />
          <Main />
          <NextScript />

          <div id="fb-root"></div>

          <div id="fb-customer-chat" className="fb-customerchat"></div>
          <Script strategy="lazyOnload">
            {`
              facebook scripts
            `}
          </Script>
        </body>
      </Html>
    );
  }
}
```

It not work only one time. So do you have another way for the facebook script just run one time and display for every pages?